# String not concatenating with char that gets updated with each loop

Tags: java, string, loops, variables

I'm trying to make a program that for every nth word, the word in the string gets reversed. However, I've run into a lot of confusion with how variables in loops go, because instead of reversing the word it actually makes the entire thing blank. This is my code, which is just a return method of the reversing process of the main program;

```
public static String reverse(String s, int n) {

    String[] parts = s.split(" "); //separating each word of the string into parts of an array
    String finalS = ""; //this will be the new string that is printed with all the words reversed\
    char a;

    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {

        int wordCount = i + 1; //making it so that it's never 0 so it can't enter the if gate if just any number is entered

        if (wordCount%n==0) { //it's divisible by n, therefore, we can reverse
            String newWord = parts[i]; //this word we've come across is the word we're dealing with, let's make a new string variable for it
            for (int i2 = newWord.length(); i2==-1; i2--){
                a = newWord.charAt(i2);
                finalS += a;
            }
        }
        else {
            finalS += parts[i]; //if it's a normal word, just gets added to the string
        }

        if (i!=parts.length) {
            finalS += " ";
        } //if it's not the last part of the string, it adds a space after the word
    }

    return finalS;
}
```

Every word other than the nth one returns perfect with no change, but the nth words just have whitespace. I feel this is due to variables not talking to each other in and out of loops. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i2 = newWord.length(); i2==-1; i2--){
```

This loop will never do anything.  It looks like you probably want

```
for (int i2 = newWord.length() - 1; i2 >= 0; i2--){
```

The second component of a `for` loop is a condition that must be true to go *into* the loop, not the condition to end the loop.

Comment: Thank you so much that's perfect!!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the statement about what the for loop is doing, but you're also going to want to change either the initial value of a, or change from a post-decrement to a pre-decrement in your loop...

Either

```
for (int i2 = newWord.length() - 1; i2 >= 0; i2--)
```

Or

```
for (int i2 = newWord.length(); i2 >= 0; --i2)
```

Otherwise you'll get an index overstepping bounds error